# Firebase Functions returns error of Bandwidth Exhausted

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We are using Firebase Functions with a few different HTTP functions .

One of the functions runs via a manual trigger from our website. It then pulls in a lot of data from an external resource and saves it into our Firestore database. Our function resources are Node.js 10, 1 GB of Memory and 540s before it times out.

However, when we have large datasets that we need to pull in, e.g. 5 000 - 10 000 records to write to the database, we start running into issues. We receive an error on large data sets of:

```
8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Bandwidth exhausted
```

The full error on Firebase Functions Health Dashboard logs looks like this:

```
Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Bandwidth exhausted
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:176:52)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:342:141)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:305:181)
at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:117:74)
at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:156:22)
at Http2CallStream.endCall (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:142:18)
at ClientHttp2Stream.stream.on (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:420:22)
at ClientHttp2Stream.emit (events.js:198:13)
at ClientHttp2Stream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
```

Our Firebase project is on the blaze plan and also, on GCP connected to an active billing account.

Upon inspection on GCP, it seems like we are NOT exceeding our WRITES per minute quote, as previously thought, however, we are exceeding our **Cloud Build** limit. We are also using batched writes when we save data to firestore from within the function, which seems to also make the amount of db writes less. e.g.

[image]

We don't use Cloud Build, so I assume that Firebase Functions uses Cloud Build in the back end to run the functions or something, but I can't find any documentation on the matter. We also have a few firestore database functions that run when documents are created. Not sure if that uses Cloud build in the back end or not.

Any idea why this would happen ? Whenever this happens, our function gets terminated with that error which causes us to only import half of our data. The data import works flawlessly with smaller amounts of data.

See our usage here for this particular project:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Build is used during the deployment of Cloud Functions. If you check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-functions) you can see that:

> Deployments work by uploading an archive containing your function's source code to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. Once the source code has been uploaded, Cloud Build automatically builds your code into a container image and pushes that image to Container Registry. Cloud Functions uses that image to create the container that executes your function.

This by itself is not enough to justify the charges you are seeing, but if you check the [container image documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building#characteristics_of_the_default_process) it says:

> Because the entire build process takes place within the context of your project, the project is subject to the pricing of the included resources:
>
> - For Cloud Build pricing, see the Pricing page. This process uses the default instance size of Cloud Build, as these instances are pre-warmed and are available more quickly. Cloud Build does provide a free tier: please review the pricing document for further details.

So with that information in mind, I would make an educated guess that your website is triggering the HTTP function enough times to make Cloud Functions scale up this particular function with new intances of it, which triggers a build process for the container that hosts the function and charges you as a Cloud Build charge. So to keep doing what you doing you are going to have to increase your Cloud Build Quota to meet this demand of your website.

Answer (score 0):

There was a Firestore trigger that was triggering on new records of the same type I was importing.

So in short, I was creating thousands of records in a collection, and for every one of those, the firestore rule (function) triggered, but what I did not know at the time, is that it created a new build process in the background for each firestore trigger that ran, which is not documented anywhere.